# Varnish + nginx + Turpentine: Making 'Allowed IPs' work

Tags: nginx, varnish, turpentine

so I have a Magento instance running with Varnish in front (port 80) and nginx running in the back on port 8080. [Turpentine](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine) does all the Magento hole-punching magic.

There are quite a few resources on making the `REMOTE_ADDR` work so that the Developer Client Restrictions under Admin -> Advanced -> Developer work properly based on my IP. The thing is that the resources are conflicting and I am seeking a best practice way to handle this in 2014.

Comment: could you point out some of the ressources and tell me what part of their solutions you don't like?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer it's not about what I don't like - my question is about what someone with experience would recommend as I see multiple solutions and I cannot see which is best practice.

Comment: Hm, could you post some links to solutions? I haven't come across this issue yet, but looks interesting.